# How do you know when to return false from a jQuery function?

Tags: jquery

"**`return false`**" seems to work in the `submitHandler` but I'm not sure why.

```
function submitHandler() {
    $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), null, "script");
    return false;
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#top_cat').submit(submitHandler);

    $("#tip_click").click(function() {
        $("#high_hat").submit(submitHandler);
    });

});
```

I'm also not sure if I need to add a "**`return false`**" in the `#tip_click` function so that it reads like this:

```
    $("#tip_click").click(function() {
        $("#high_hat").submit(submitHandler);
        return false;
    });
```

***What's the rule to follow here regarding when to "`return false`"?***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should `return false` when:

- You want to prevent the default event action

  - The `onsubmit` event for example, the default action of this event is send the form data to the server, or an `onclick` event on an anchor element, the default event action is to follow the anchor's HREF.
- You want to stop the event bubbling.

Returning false from an event handler, is like executing both [`event.preventDefault();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.preventDefault) and [`event.stopPropagation();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.stopPropagation).