# jquery: returning true or false

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you know when to return false from a jQuery function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635401/how-do-you-know-when-to-return-false-from-a-jquery-function)

We all have some jquery code that looks like this:

```
$('#MySelector').somefunction(function () {

   // do something

});
```

Is there a benefit/penalty for including a return statement and should we return true or false? For now, I'd say my code works fine without the return statements but I was wondering what would a return statement do in the context I described.

Thanks for your clarifications.

Comment: I dunno, what does `somefunction` do?

Comment: *"...in the context I described."* You haven't described any knowable context, unless there's a `somefunction` plugin that everyone but me knows about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the anonymous function as a parameter to `somefunction`, so it really depends on what `somefunction` does with that parameter.  What really matters is what `somefunction` returns.  For example, let's say this is how it's defined:

```
$.fn.somefunction = function ( fnParam ) {
  var returnVal = fnParam();

  if (returnVal) {
    // do something
  } else {
    // do something else
  }

  return this;
};
```

So here we assign the return value of `fnParam` to a variable and use that variable to determine actions within `somefunction`.  `somefunction` returns `this` though, which would be the jQuery object that it was passed (in your example `$('#MySelector')`).  Since you return `this`, `somefunction` can chain with other jQuery methods like:

```
$('#MySelector').somefunction(function(){ // blah })
                .css('background','yellow')
                .appendTo('body')
                .show();
```

Answer (score 2):

For `return false`, this is a good read, [jQuery Events: Stop (Mis)Using Return False](http://web.archive.org/web/20160614140933/http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/).

Answer (score 0):

in this case, if you use

```
return false;
```

it aborts that `function(){ }` and continues if possible

Answer (score 0):

Returning something is only beneficial if you want to exit out of the function prematurely and/or if you need to assign the value of the function's result to a variable:

```
var foo = calculate(1,2); // foo = 3

function calculate(a,b){
    return a+b;
}
```

Comment: I think he does know what does it mean in your case. He wants to know what happens in case of his CONTEXT $("body").some(function(){ return; });

Comment: Yea I was assuming so, but it was a pretty ridiculous question anyway so I wasn't sure after all ;)